ZenithZ89 System Font
What is the font (ttf name ideally) used in the ZenithZ89 System Font?
(This is a retro question - if one were to emulate it using currently available fonts, which would be used?)

FWIW: GraphicDesign.SE has a name this font identification tag

@Greenonline - I believe that [graphicdesign.se] requires an image of the font, and a showing of effort to have identified the font using one or more of the myriad font-identification sites on the web. Even here, if it's on-topic, an image of the font in question would be useful.

Based on this image, it looks like any number of typical 5x7 bitmap fonts. Looking at it in a browser-based emulator, it has true descenders for lowercase, which makes it actually an apparent 5x9 bitmap font with 2-pixel descender.

The part of the Zenith Z89 you're interested in is the Heathkit H19. This is the component which contains the font you're asking about.
This font can be found here.
As I mentioned in a comment, a TTF font is probably not what you're looking for. I think you should use a bitmap font.

That emulator adds blank lines to the font data to simulate CRT scan lines. The results may not be what's expected.

@scruss Maybe, maybe not. But anyhow the font data is in the file Src/h19-font.h. I figured OP would just get the data from there and massage it into whatever format OP wanted

no, there absolutely have been blank lines introduced into the font data. No maybe about it. The C source does not match the bitmap data in the file h19.zip from the MAME Heathkit H89 Emulator page.

@scruss Oh I see what you're saying now, yes. There are blank lines in the font. It's possible that's undesirable for OP (what I meant by "maybe" and what you meant by "may"). Either way, these blank lines should be easy enough to remove.

The original character ROM of the H19 can be found at the bottom of this page, along with third-party character ROMs for enhanced versions of the system (SuperSet and GP19).
Once you have the ROM, if you still find you want a font in TTF format this Stack Overflow answer describes using FontForge and AutoTrace to convert a bitmap font to TrueType format.

There's a maybe-good-enough-to-do OTF file here: scruss/HeathkitH19Font: an attempt to create an outline font of the Heathkit H19 terminal font. It was quite an involved process.

HeathkitH19Font
an incomplete attempt to create an outline font of the Heathkit H19 terminal font, after crt monitor - ZenithZ89 System Font - Retrocomputing Stack Exchange
Process
From the ROM file 2716_444-29_h19font.bin extracted from h19.zip at MAME Heathkit H89 Emulator it is fairly clear that 128 characters are encoded as blocks of 10 bytes out of every 16:
00000000: 1818 1818 1818 1818 1818 0000 0000 0000  ................ # char 0x00
00000010: 0000 0000 ffff 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................ # char 0x01
00000020: 1818 1818 ffff 1818 1818 0000 0000 0000  ................ # char 0x02
 ...
00000200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................ # char 0x20, SPACE
00000210: 0008 0808 0808 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................ # char 0x21, EXCLAMATION MARK
 ...
000007f0: 0000 1c3e 3e3e 1c00 0000 0000 0000 0000  ...>>>.......... # char 0x7f

The first 32 characters are graphic characters, and don't correspond to any currently used encoding.
The character data can be extracted and joined as contiguous data using:
for i in {0..127}
do
  dd if=2716_444-29_h19font.bin bs=1 skip="$((i * 16))" count=10 of="$(printf 'h19-%02x.bin' ${i})" status=none
done
cat h19-*.bin > raw-h19.bin

John Elliott's PSF Tools can be used to convert this raw binary file into slightly more useful standard bitmap font files:
raw2psf --height=10 --width=8 --first=0 --last=127 raw-h19.bin h19.psf
psf2bdf --first=0 --last=127 --fontname=HeathkitH19 --descent=2 --defchar=9 h19.psf HeathkitH19.bdf

Note that the Bitmap Distribution Format (BDF) file created is effectively un-encoded. It does, however, contain all of the bitmap characters.
bdf2sfd did the heavy lifting of converting from a bitmap to an initial traced outline:
bdf2sfd -f 'Heathkit-H19 Regular' HeathkitH19.bdf > Heathkit-H19-Regular.sfd

Re-encoding
The non-ASCII characters were re-encoded using FontForge like so:
U+00B1  ±   PLUS-MINUS SIGN
U+00B6  ¶   PILCROW SIGN
U+00F7  ÷   DIVISION SIGN
U+2022  •   BULLET
U+2192  →   RIGHTWARDS ARROW
U+2193  ↓   DOWNWARDS ARROW
U+2501  ━   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY HORIZONTAL
U+2503  ┃   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL
U+250F  ┏   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY DOWN AND RIGHT
U+2513  ┓   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY DOWN AND LEFT
U+2517  ┗   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY UP AND RIGHT
U+251B  ┛   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY UP AND LEFT
U+2523  ┣   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL AND RIGHT
U+252B  ┫   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL AND LEFT
U+2533  ┳   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY DOWN AND HORIZONTAL
U+253B  ┻   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY UP AND HORIZONTAL
U+254B  ╋   BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY VERTICAL AND HORIZONTAL
U+2571  ╱   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER RIGHT TO LOWER LEFT
U+2572  ╲   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER LEFT TO LOWER RIGHT
U+2573  ╳   BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL CROSS
U+2580  ▀   UPPER HALF BLOCK
U+2582  ▂   LOWER ONE QUARTER BLOCK
U+258E  ▎   LEFT ONE QUARTER BLOCK
U+2590  ▐   RIGHT HALF BLOCK
U+2592  ▒   MEDIUM SHADE
U+2596  ▖   QUADRANT LOWER LEFT
U+2597  ▗   QUADRANT LOWER RIGHT
U+2598  ▘   QUADRANT UPPER LEFT
U+259D  ▝   QUADRANT UPPER RIGHT
U+25E4  ◤   BLACK UPPER LEFT TRIANGLE
U+25E5  ◥   BLACK UPPER RIGHT TRIANGLE
U+1FB82   UPPER ONE QUARTER BLOCK
U+1FB87   RIGHT ONE QUARTER BLOCK

Note that the upper and lower quarter block mapping is not quite 100% accurate. The H19 font is 10 px high, but there is no ONE FIFTH BLOCK in Unicode (yet).
The obvious holes in the symbol set were likely meant to have been covered by reverse video. This is no longer easily available to us.
TBD

clean up the inevitable mess this process made.

Licence
 Heathkit H19 Terminal Font by Stewart Russell is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0
